# Package name suggestion in fedora

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, fedora, yum

In Ubuntu when an app is not installed and in Terminal you type for example `gvim` it says that this app is contained in package `vim-gnome` and try installing that but in fedora that doesn't happen with yum and it just says `command not found`.

My question is:
is there any way to add this feature or something similar to fedora?  and if not how should I install an app that I don't know it's package name.

Answer (score 1):

Yum should not be saying command not found. For example, if you type:

```
yum install gvims
```

and the package is not found, then it should inform you that the package has not been found.

If you are trying to find out what package will give you a certain file, then you can type:

```
yum provides "*/gvim"
```

The "*/" part of the command will search in any path, so it would match /bin/gvim, /usr/bin/gvim, and so on. In other words, the "*" is a wildcard. So, you could type "*/*gvim" and that would match s-gvim, anything-before-gvim.

You can also search for packages by typing:

```
yum search gvim
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Fedora Wiki page](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackageKitCommandNotFound) for the command-not-found package.

Essentially:

- install `PackageKit-command-not-found` package:

```
yum install PackageKit-command-not-found
```

- Restart your terminal, or log out and log in again
- Ensure the powertop package is removed from the system. Then type `powertop`, and verify output is:

> Command not found. Install package 'powertop' to provide command 'powertop'? [N/y]

- You can edit system policy by changing the `/etc/PackageKit/CommandNotFound.conf` file.

Comment: It is installed but doesn't work. when I enter `gdeit` it says `Similar command is: 'gedit'` but when I enter gvim it prints only `bash: gvim: command not found...`

Comment: Note that the followup continues in [a new question about why this doesn't work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82811/fedoras-command-not-found-doesnt-work)