# Fedora's command-not-found doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, package-management, yum

I've recently installed Fedora 19. [Packagekit-command-not-found](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/PackageKitCommandNotFound) is installed. But its own examples don't work. When I enter `gedti` the output is:

```
bash: gedti: command not found... Similar command is: 'gedit'
```

And it works correctly but when I enter powertop, the output is:

```
bash: powertop: command not found...
```

With no suggestion about the package. Why? Should I edit some configuration files or update some cache or ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely some weirdness with PackageKit. I already had `powertop` installed but wanted to test out what you're having issues with.

```
$ rpm -ql PackageKit-command-not-found
/etc/PackageKit/CommandNotFound.conf
/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh
/usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found
```

So from the above you can run the command that PackageKit will run to do the search like so:

```
$ /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found <command>
```

#### Example

```
$ /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found powertop
bash: powertop: command not found...

$ which powertop
/usr/bin/powertop
```

Running it a 2nd time I got it to recommend `powertop`:

```
$ /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found powertop
bash: powertop: command not found...
Install package 'powertop' to provide command 'powertop'? [N/y]
```

#### So why isn't it finding powertop?

I think that ultimately the root cause is the timeout that's defined in the config file: `/etc/PackageKit/CommandNotFound.conf`:

```
MaxSearchTime=2000
```

This timeout is to cap how long PackageKit will take to do it's query. The query is not against your local Yum cache, it's searching live against Yum repositories that you have configured on the internet. Therefore if you want it to be more thorough vs. more performant you have the following trade-off:

```
# aggressive find
MaxSearchTime=15000

# more responsive
MaxSearchTime=250
```

Comment: I did the same but didn't get the recommendation.

Comment: @Farzam What's your timeout set to in the `CommandNotFound.conf` file?

Comment: I've set it to 15000, 150000, 1500000, ... but didn't work. Does it connect to internet? Can I add -C flag to its search command?

Comment: @Farzam - it uses a different mechanism that the completion.

Comment: so what should I do? It also doesn't work when I'm disconnected from the internet.

Comment: @Farzam - I was tracing the executable, `pk-command-not-found` using `strace` to see what the program does. You can try it if you're curious: `strace /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found powertop`. I see it sending messages to something else, but I couldn't peek inside to see what it was sending those messages to. Most likely another daemon/service but until today I've never even played with PackageKit so I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: so is it working fine in your system just like Ubuntu?

Comment: @Farzam - I'm using Fedora, the same as you. It works on Fedora & CentOS systems that I have here. The daemon it's talking to is called `/usr/libexec/packagekitd`. I'll have to download F19 and try it in there. I don't have any boxes with that particular version setup as of yet.

Comment: @Farzam - you might want to look through the packagekit FAQ: http://www.packagekit.org/pk-faq.html

Comment: @Farzam An alternate approach is to leave this out and type "yum search all _commandname_" whenever you hit something that isn't installed but you think should be. It's less magical, but it also doesn't cause a search to happen with every typo.